# React Hook cannot be called within a function

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Hello I am using react hooks within one of my components, however I have done things in a similar fashion with other components and no problems but now the code below produces a error of

[image]

my code below

```
const supplierDetails = props => {


  const [suppliers, setSupplierList] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    getSupplierData().then(response => {
      setSupplierList(response);
    });
  }, []);

  return (
    <div>
      {suppliers && <SupplierDetails suppliers={suppliers} />}
    </div>

  );

};

export default supplierDetails;
```

Comment: How are you using your functional component here? Also, shouldn't it be by convention `SupplierDetails` instead?

Comment: Sure looks confusing having 2 components with same name with exception of cap/lowercase for first letter. How are you using `supplierDetails`?

Comment: yes the naming convention is a bit backwards but still not entirely sure why this would cause such an error

Comment: the linter is statically checking the code.  It sees a lower-case function and therefore assumes it is *not* a React component and so complains about hook usage in a regular function.

Answer (score 2):

React Components should always start with an uppercase char so they can be differed from normal html tags. If you want to use hooks change the name to `SupplierDetails` of course this will throw an error because you already have a component named `SupplierDetails`. So you could put a number or something to tell then apart: `SupplierDetails2`